# Foreign National has Resident Account in Indian and transfer money overseas

Tags: india, salary, singapore

I am an expat working in India, my salary is paid to my Resident savings account. How do i remit my salary to my wife in Singapore for the family's maintenance? The bank made a mistake and opened a Resident instead of an Expat account. Can I still transfer my salary home?

Comment: Have the bank fix the issue.  Or, just open a NEW account at a NEW bank, and trash that one.

Answer (score 1):

You can still transfer the funds via wire transfer, for small amounts there are no restrictions. You would need to visit the bank to do an international wire transfer.

It is recommended that you open a FA resident savings account or current account.